# Integration with matrices

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have written two equations in matrix format as follows

$m(t)={\begin{pmatrix}
        200\\ 
        300\\ 
        400\\ 
        500
        \end{pmatrix}}^T
          \begin{pmatrix}
        \phi_1(t)\\ 
        \phi_2(t)\\ 
         \phi_3(t)\\
          \phi_4(t)\\ 
      \end{pmatrix} \tag1$

$n(t)={\begin{pmatrix}
        200\\ 
        300\\ 
        400\\ 
        500
        \end{pmatrix}}^T
          \begin{pmatrix}
        \psi_1(t)\\ 
        \psi_2(t)\\ 
         \psi_3(t)\\
          \psi_4(t)\\ 
      \end{pmatrix} \tag1$

Is it possible to write an expression for  the following questions with out multiplying the the constant matrices with variable matrices.? I imply a matrix form for integration.  ( For example I can write  $ \int m(t) dt  ={\begin{pmatrix}
        200\\ 
        300\\ 
        400\\ 
        500
        \end{pmatrix}}^T
          \begin{pmatrix}
       \int \phi_1(t)dt\\ 
       \int \phi_2(t)dt\\ 
        \int \phi_3(t)dt\\
         \int \phi_4(t)dt\\ 
      \end{pmatrix} +C$ . I assume I am correct.)

**Question**

1. What could be the matrix format for $\int m(t)^2 \ dt $ in a similar matrix format   as shown in the given example above?
2. What could be the matrix format for $\int m(t)n(t) \ dt $ in a similar format as  shown in the given example above?